# Order of signals: SIGPOLL and SIGCHLD

Tags: process, pipe, signals

I spawn a child process and connect to it with a pipe.

I configure the pipe to send `SIGPOLL` on data available by `fcntl` `I_SETSIG`.

The child sends some data over the pipe and then terminates.

Can I be sure that `SIGPOLL` will be received before `SIGCHLD`? (or may in this situation I receive only `SIGCHLD` without `SIGPOLL` at all? If I receive both signals, can I be sure about their order?)

I use Perl on FreeBSD, but this question extends to all Unix platforms.

Comment: Your other process will most certainly terminate with a broken pipe before receiving the last bits of information.  Adding a delay might be the easiest solution but a proper solution would be to determine a way for the child to get confirmation that the message was received, and then quit.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The child process **sends** information not receives it. So I doubt validity of your comment

Comment: You could actually be right depending on exactly how it is programmed.  But my point remains that the only way to be sure the signal is received is to get a form of validation or otherwise you're just guessing.

Comment: That's like listening to someone's last words, you may or may not hear them properly and you'll never have a chance to confirm whether you did because it's too late.  That's just a bad design.

Comment: The order in which signals are delivered is undefined.  If you have a single child you might get away with blocking `SIGCHLD` until you receive `SIGPOLL`, but it's still bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design has race condition written all over it. You can't be certain that the signals will be delivered in order, or even at all. If you're using Perl that makes it doubly uncertain.

Redesign so that there's some confirmation from parent to child that the data got received. Signal delivery order and number is an unreliable thing, asking for a portable solution is even more hopeless.